# How to prevent the action of adding \n when pressing Shift + Enter in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am using textarea to enter text and every time i send text, i have to press `Shift` + `Enter` 
but when the text is sent it adds `/n` at the end, I'm using the `Enter` newline key instead of submit

**Ex**: hello => hello\n

Image not selected send by key enter:
[image: not selected send by enter]
here is my code:

```js
    checkSubmitKey() {
      if (!this.isEnterSubmit) {
        this.sendMessage();
      }
    },
    
    
    onChangeInput() {
      this.getTextareaRef().addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
        this.handlesaveDraftMessages()
        if (e.key === "Enter" && !e.shiftKey && this.isEnterSubmit) {
          this.sendMessage();
          this.resizeTextarea();
        }
      });
      this.resizeTextarea();
    },
    
    
    resizeTextarea() {
      const el = this.getTextareaRef();

      if (!el) {
        return;
      }

      el.style.height = "auto";
      let newHeight = el.scrollHeight;
      el.style.height = `${newHeight}px`;
    },
```

```html
<textarea
     rows="1"
     id="roomTextarea"
     ref="roomTextarea"
     v-model="messageInput"
     :placeholder="$t('containers.admin.chat.chatPlaceholder')"
     class="room-footer-reply-textarea"
     @keyup="onChangeInput"
     @keyup.enter.shift.exact.prevent="checkSubmitKey"
     @click.self="checkmarkSeen"
     @paste="onPasteClipboard"
 />
```

how do i fix the above 
thanks for your help !

Comment: What about just removing your newline before sending the message? You can detect the Enter, so you can control what happens with the text before being sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `keyup`, use `keydown` event and then `preventDefault()` while <kbd>Enter</kbd> is hit without <kbd>shift</kbd> key:

```js
document.querySelector('textarea').addEventListener('keydown', e => {
  if(e.key === 'Enter' && !e.shiftKey) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('send:', e.target.value);
  }
});
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```

Comment: Thank you, can't believe I missed it  e.preventDefault()